# How to install libpthread.a in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: pthreads, ubuntu-14.04

I'm looking for libpthread.a ( Static library ) for my 64 bit machine.
Now, I have shared library in my system.

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so  
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
```

Is there any way to get static libaray with only "apt-get install" ?

Kazu

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On my system:

```
~$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a
libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Apt-get Install

```
sudo apt-get install libpthread-stubs0-dev
```

Result:

```
[sudo] password for administrator: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libntdb1 python-ntdb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpthread-stubs0-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 71 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,068 B of archives.
After this operation, 41.0 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libpthread-stubs0-dev amd64 0.3-4 [4,068 B]
Fetched 4,068 B in 0s (8,675 B/s)          
Selecting previously unselected package libpthread-stubs0-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 177941 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpthread-stubs0-dev_0.3-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpthread-stubs0-dev:amd64 (0.3-4) ...
Setting up libpthread-stubs0-dev:amd64 (0.3-4) ...
```

#### Find libpthread.a

```
ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ |grep libpthread
```

Result:

```
libpthread.a
libpthread_nonshared.a
libpthread.so
```